# Getting a FileNotFoundError [Errno2] when moving files using shutil move() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

My main goal is to observe my downloads folder using watchdog in python and move the downloaded file into a different folder so all the files stay in one place.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
import shutil

file_extension = ["dmg", "jpg", "pdf", "docx", "zip", "tar", "jpeg", "mp4,", "mp3", "png"]
src = '/Users/vibhorsagar/Downloads'
path = os.listdir(src)


class Watcher:

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(handler, src, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
            c = Cleaner()
            for i in file_extension:
                if event.src_path.endswith(i):
                    c.clean(i, event.src_path)
                else:
                    print("Error 2")

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)

        elif event.event_type == 'moved':
            print("Received moved event - %s." % event.src_path)


class Cleaner():

    def clean(self, file_type, file):
        if file_type == "dmg":
            shutil.move(file, '/Users/vibhorsagar/dmgs')

        if file_type == "jpg" or "png" or "jpeg":
            shutil.move(file, '/Users/vibhorsagar/Pictures')

        if file_type == "pdf":
            shutil.move(file, '/Users/vibhorsagar/pdfs')

        if file_type == "docx":
            shutil.move(file, '/Users/vibhorsagar/docx')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

When I drop a file in the downloads folder, it moves the file to the destination folder but gives me this error:

```
Received created event - /Users/vibhorsagar/Downloads/Kite.dmg.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 803, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/vibhorsagar/Downloads/Kite.dmg' -> '/Users/vibhorsagar/Pictures/Kite.dmg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 203, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 376, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/watchdog/events.py", line 330, in dispatch
    self.on_any_event(event)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/Python Projects/cleaner/clean.py", line 44, in on_any_event
    c.clean(i, event.src_path)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/Python Projects/cleaner/clean.py", line 77, in clean
    shutil.move(file, '/Users/vibhorsagar/Pictures')
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 817, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Users/vibhorsagar/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/vibhorsagar/Downloads/Kite.dmg'
```

Why is it looking for the file after it's moved? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I could be wrong; but a possible reason is a race condition.  It's trying to move the file while the system is writing to the said file.   Perhaps adding some sort of test to see if the file is readable before proceeding?

Comment: Agree with @ewong — your code is probably attempting to move the file before it has finished being downloading. You should use a `try`/`except FileNotFoundError:` and retry the operation after a `time.sleep()` call (up to some limited maximum number of times).